# Clojure: (seven weeks seven languages) get type of collection and print - feedback on my solution?

Tags: clojure

I'm learning about Clojure using the book *Seven Weeks Seven Languages* and I'm feeling like I'm missing the point and/or not getting it.

Question:

> Write a function called (collection-type col) that returns :list, :map,
>   or :vector based on the type of collection col.

My Solution:

```
(defn collection-type
    "returns collection type for list map or vector"
    [col]
    (def look-up {:list "class clojure.lang.PersistentList", :map "class clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap", :vector "class clojure.lang.PersistentVector"})
    (if (= (look-up :list) (str (type col))) (println :list))
    (if (= (look-up :map) (str (type col))) (println :map))
    (if (= (look-up :vector) (str (type col))) (println :vector)))
```

It works fine but I feel like I'm missing the point, does anyone have any insight/advice/guidance here? It just seems so ugly and in-elegant.

Comment: `def` can only create globals. As such, it is usually out of place inside a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other answers depend on testing the concrete type of the collection which is fraught with danger.

Maps for example have a different concrete implementation for different sizes as a performance optimization.

Consider:

```
(type {})
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap

(type (zipmap (range 100) (range 100)))
;=> clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap
```

Since clojure already has predicates to test for the necessary collections why not use those and make the solution more robust

```
(defn collection-type [coll] (condp #(%1 %2) coll
                                    map?    :map
                                    vector? :vector
                                    list?   :list))
```

Comment: This solution is correct. [Mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25781572/1562315) is wrong.

Comment: Since my question was really only asking for feedback, I wouldn't say your answer was "wrong", but I'll mark this as the accepted answer anyway. Thanks to all of you! Very helpful.

Comment: @ceruleus Glad to be of help. I have transformed your answer and answered your question in an enlightening way (he said modestly). But you say that your solution "works fine". It doesn't. Neither does my improvement of it. For example, if you `assoc` new entries onto an empty map, you'll currently find it changes type at count 10 and ceases to be recognized by our code: You can test this with `(first (drop-while collection-type (reductions #(assoc %1 %2 %2) {} (range))))`. This is an accident waiting to happen.

Answer (score 3):

*Edit*

Although the following answers the question, it does not mend the fault in the offered code noted by [@sw1nn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786382/1562315).

---

How can we simplify this?

- Compute with the *types*, not their string representations.
- Invert the `look-up` map to give the keyword-tag of a given type.
- *Return* the value. Leave the caller to print it.

Using the `look-up` map as a function (as you already do), we get

```
(defn collection-type
  "returns collection type for list map or vector"
  [coll]
  (let [look-up {clojure.lang.PersistentList     :list
                 clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap :map
                 clojure.lang.PersistentVector   :vector}]
    (look-up (type coll))))
```

Then

```
(collection-type [])
;:vector

(collection-type (list 1))
;:list
```

But

```
(collection-type ())
;nil
```

since

```
(type ())
;clojure.lang.PersistentList$EmptyList
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was hoping for. You've shown me some nice features of clojure's api that I wasn't aware of and got rid of the strings that were really bothering me. I hadn't even considered return values yet so thanks for that as well.

Comment: Good! Also note that - in accord with @noisesmith's comment - `let` replaced `def` for defining `look-up`. If you want others to access `look-up`, move `def` to the outermost level, so that it is only executed once.